# BIT data type works differently in SQL Server 2005 and 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a table with a column of `bit` data type.

In my java class I have boolean values `true/false`, I am saving those values to the database and it is saved successfully.

But here the problem is: that boolean value saved with `true/false` format in SQL Server 2005, but it is saved in SQL Server 2008 as `0` or `1`.

What is there difference between these two servers, I am confused.

Comment: Can you share schema for the table in both 2005 and 2008 and provide a sample repro for us to test